# How to avoid element being overwritten by second loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I want to generate an array using two loops and a given equation. In my code, the first for-loop overwrites each time the elements that were generated in the previous run. My array ends up having only the last set of elements (for a=9). Here is the code:

```
%Pixel information generated 

n=3
m=3

for a=7:9

    for r=1:3
      k(r)=a+ (r-1)*(n*m)
      disp(k);
      r=r+1
    end
a=a+1
end
```

How can I avoid this and obtain all values of `K` for each value of "a"?

Thanks
Manoj

Comment: Yua can try using something like `k(a,r)` or, since `a` starts from `7` you can define a counter for the first index (to be initialized to `1` before the beginning on the first loop and incremented at the end of the first loop). Also notice that the indeces of the loops (`a` and `r`) are autonatically incremented therefore you should not do `r=r+1` and `a=a+1".

Comment: Thanks, k(a,r) generates 3 x 9 matrix rather than 3 x 3, but within that matrix, the correct 3 x 3 matrix also exist.

Comment: Why was the question  down voted?, i cant understand the reason!

Comment: @Manoj I can't say for certain why you were downvoted, because I didn't do it, but it probably relates to the first line you see when you hover your mouse over the down arrow "This question does not show any research effort". Your problem involves basic MATLAB (and programming) that would be better answered by a good tutorial than on Stack Overflow. @il_raffa already told you that your loop index from 7 to 9 would be a problem and how to avoid it. Alternatively, you could use `k(a-6,r)`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `r` is your index, your index will only vary from 1 to 3. And this each time you go through the first loop. Therefore, you need an independent index. You also don't need to increase `r` and `a` because the for-loop function does this automatically. Last, it's better to work with a cell array for `k` because it keeps growing throughout the for-loops.

**Code**:

```
n=3;
m=3;

k = cell(1,1); % cell array
index = 1; % independent index

for a=7:9

    for r=1:3
      k{index}=a+(r-1)*(n*m);
      index = index + 1;
    end

end

k = cell2mat(k)
```

**Output**:

```
k =

     7    16    25     8    17    26     9    18    27
```

Comment: @Manoj, is this what you are looking for?